# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in shopify custom cart popup jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

I get error in my jQuery AJAX code. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. I don't understand how I can fix this. When I try to add product by click in variant this error is showing. Here is my shopify [development](https://myrx-shop.myshopify.com/) site. Below is my jQuery code.

```
$('.varients-item').on('click', function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var variants_id = $(this).attr("data-variant");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: {
            quantity: 1,
            id: variants_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: '/cart.json',
                success: function(cart){

                    var item_count = cart['item_count'];
                    var total_price = cart['total_price']/100;

                    //If there are items in cart
                    if ( item_count > 0 ) {
                        // cart count
                        $('.cart-item-count span').text(item_count);

                        // mini cart data
                        $('.cart-popup').attr('id','cartPopup');
                        $('.cartpopup-total .price').text( '£' + total_price.toFixed(2) );


                        var cart_list = [];

                        for( var i = 0; i < item_count; i++ ){
                            if ( cart['items'][i]['id'] != null ) {
                                var item_id = cart['items'][i]['id'];
                                var product_title = cart['items'][i]['product_title'];
                                // var product_title = data['items'][i]['title'];
                                var product_handle = cart['items'][i]['handle'];
                                var quantity = cart['items'][i]['quantity'];
                                var line_price = cart['items'][i]['price']/100;
                                var url = cart['items'][i]['url'];
                                var image_url = cart['items'][i]['image'];
                                var variants = cart['items'][i]['variant_options'];

                                if ( product_title == 'Gift Wrap' ) {
                                    var product_url = product_title;
                                } else {
                                    var product_url = '<a href="' + url + '">' + product_title + '</a>';
                                }

                                var options = [];
                                for ( var o = 0; o < variants.length; o++ ) {
                                    var selected = cart['items'][i]['variant_options'][o];
                                    if ( selected !== 'Default Title' ) {
                                        options.push( selected + '<br>' );
                                    }
                                };
                                var selected_options = options.join('');

                                cart_list.push(
                                    '<div class="cartpopup-item d-flex flex-row">'+
                                        '<div class="cartpopup-item-image">'+
                                            '<a href="' + url + '">'+
                                                '<img class="img-fluid d-block" src="' + image_url + '"  alt="' + product_title + '" />'+
                                            '</a>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="cartpopup-item-content d-flex flex-column">'+
                                            '<h5>' + product_url + '</h5>'+
                                            '<span class="variant">' + selected_options + '</span>'+
                                            '<span class="price">£' + total_price.toFixed(2) + '</span>'+
                                            '<div class="quantity-box d-flex flex-row">'+
                                                '<button class="quantity-button qminus" role="button" type="button" data-variant="' + item_id + '"><i class="fal fa-minus"></i></button>'+
                                                '<input class="quantity-input" type="number" disabled name="updates[]" id="updates_' + item_id + '" value="' + quantity + '" min="1" />'+
                                                '<button class="quantity-button qplus" role="button" type="button" data-variant="' + item_id + '"><i class="fal fa-plus"></i></button>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                            '<div class="d-flex flex-row">'+
                                                '<a class="remove" data-cart-remove-id="' + item_id + '" href="/cart/change?line=' + item_count + '&amp;quantity=0">Remove</a>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'
                                );
                            } //endif
                        }; // endfor

                        $('.cartpopup-body').html( cart_list.join('') );
                    }
                    $('.cart-popup').addClass('active');
                    $('body').addClass('cartpopup-active');
                    $('body').append(
                        '<div class="popupbackdrop"></div>'
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**This error will show when try to add same variant two times on click in variant button**. When remove all products from cart and refresh page then add product again it will work perfectly.

> I'm struggling about this issue in many days but no success.

Comment: My guess would be that `cart['items'][i]['id']` throws the error because `cart['items'][i]` is `undefined`. It's very hard to say without a [mcve].

Comment: I already add link in my question description. Please click the development link. Also I use code from this link https://gist.github.com/zoerooney/156af5751fa2580fa2b5

Comment: 1. that's not *minimal*. There is a lot of code there and I am pretty sure most of it is non-essential. 2. This is not reproducible - I don't have the data for this. 3. The link is off-site. Questions should be self-contained - when you fix that issue, this question will become worthless to future visitors who might have a similar issue or for people who want to propose alternative solutions.

Comment: For this issue it's very much impossible to showing example without Shiopify platform.

Comment: The issue is that you derefence something that's not there. It's a basic data problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this is a common problem where you are trying to access the data that is not available. In this scenario, the reason behind this is your misinterpretation of **item_count** variable in Shopify cart. If you have a look at [Shopify AJAX API](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart#get-cart-js) reference, **item_count** is the total number of items in your cart. For example, you may have **item_count** as 3 while only 1 object in items array with quantity 3. However, you code does not handle this case and always assume that number of objects will always be equal to **item_count**. Moreover, to iterate over the array, don't rely on **item_count** but on **items** array length. Doing so, your code will be like

```
$('.varients-item').on('click', function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var variants_id = $(this).attr("data-variant");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: {
            quantity: 1,
            id: variants_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: '/cart.json',
                success: function(cart){
                    // change the below line
                    var item_count = cart['items'].length;
                    var total_price = cart['total_price']/100;

                    //If there are items in cart
                    if ( item_count > 0 ) {
                        // cart count
                        $('.cart-item-count span').text(item_count);

                        // mini cart data
                        $('.cart-popup').attr('id','cartPopup');
                        $('.cartpopup-total .price').text( '£' + total_price.toFixed(2) );


                        var cart_list = [];

                        for( var i = 0; i < item_count; i++ ){
                            if ( cart['items'][i]['id'] != null ) {
                                var item_id = cart['items'][i]['id'];
                                var product_title = cart['items'][i]['product_title'];
                                // var product_title = data['items'][i]['title'];
                                var product_handle = cart['items'][i]['handle'];
                                var quantity = cart['items'][i]['quantity'];
                                var line_price = cart['items'][i]['price']/100;
                                var url = cart['items'][i]['url'];
                                var image_url = cart['items'][i]['image'];
                                var variants = cart['items'][i]['variant_options'];

                                if ( product_title == 'Gift Wrap' ) {
                                    var product_url = product_title;
                                } else {
                                    var product_url = '<a href="' + url + '">' + product_title + '</a>';
                                }

                                var options = [];
                                for ( var o = 0; o < variants.length; o++ ) {
                                    var selected = cart['items'][i]['variant_options'][o];
                                    if ( selected !== 'Default Title' ) {
                                        options.push( selected + '<br>' );
                                    }
                                };
                                var selected_options = options.join('');

                                cart_list.push(
                                    '<div class="cartpopup-item d-flex flex-row">'+
                                        '<div class="cartpopup-item-image">'+
                                            '<a href="' + url + '">'+
                                                '<img class="img-fluid d-block" src="' + image_url + '"  alt="' + product_title + '" />'+
                                            '</a>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="cartpopup-item-content d-flex flex-column">'+
                                            '<h5>' + product_url + '</h5>'+
                                            '<span class="variant">' + selected_options + '</span>'+
                                            '<span class="price">£' + total_price.toFixed(2) + '</span>'+
                                            '<div class="quantity-box d-flex flex-row">'+
                                                '<button class="quantity-button qminus" role="button" type="button" data-variant="' + item_id + '"><i class="fal fa-minus"></i></button>'+
                                                '<input class="quantity-input" type="number" disabled name="updates[]" id="updates_' + item_id + '" value="' + quantity + '" min="1" />'+
                                                '<button class="quantity-button qplus" role="button" type="button" data-variant="' + item_id + '"><i class="fal fa-plus"></i></button>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                            '<div class="d-flex flex-row">'+
                                                '<a class="remove" data-cart-remove-id="' + item_id + '" href="/cart/change?line=' + item_count + '&amp;quantity=0">Remove</a>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'
                                );
                            } //endif
                        }; // endfor

                        $('.cartpopup-body').html( cart_list.join('') );
                    }
                    $('.cart-popup').addClass('active');
                    $('body').addClass('cartpopup-active');
                    $('body').append(
                        '<div class="popupbackdrop"></div>'
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I fix this using this `i < cart.items.length;` instead of `i < item_count;` you can test from here https://myrx-shop.myshopify.com/